# BATCH - Mirrow two Folders in both Ways

Tags: windows, batch-file, robocopy

I safe some Files at my Local Drive(Laptop) and also have Files saved at my Network Storage at Work.

I want that both Folders have the same Files, If I create/delete or change an File in one Folder, the other Folder should get Updated when I use the BATCH.

It should use the newest Version on an Document.

So I tried it with `ROBOCOPY Folder01 Folder02 /MIR /R:3 /W.20`, it worked but only in one Way, from Folder01 to Folder02, so if I created an File in Folder02 and used the Batch, the File got deleted.

Then I tried to copy both Folders into one TEMP Folder and then copy the TEMP-Files to both Folders. I used
`ROBOCOPY Folder01 TEMP /XO /E /R:3 /W:20`
`ROBOCOPY Folder02 TEMP /XO /E /R:3 /W:20`
`ROBOCOPY TEMP Folder01 /MIR /R:3 /W.20`
`ROBOCOPY TEMP Folder02 /MIR /R:3 /W.20`
this was almost perfect, always the newest Document was used and everything was there, but when I delete a File from Folder01, which still exists in Folder02, it will come back next time I use my BATCH.

*Sorry for my English*
*Greetings, Tobias*

Comment: If you are working in both folders, how should `robocopy` know whether a file has been created in one folder or deleted in the other one? `robocopy` does not remember what it did during last synchronisation, so it just recognises current differences in source and destination locations...

Comment: I know that he dont know If its an Created one or an Deleted, but maybe there is a way where the Changes within a Folder gets logged or something, to check the State of the Folder with that.

_Maybe I want too much?_

Comment: For `robocopy`, you want too much; you need to search for a more powerful sync tool, or you have to write it on your own...

Comment: use the archive attribute. See `attrib /?` for info. Both `robocopy` and `xcopy` have switches to use this attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution provided by @Sachadee with `Xcopy`

```bat
:://Synchro.bat
:://SachaDee 2014
@echo off&cls
:: We set Folders to synchonized
set "Folders= C:\HackooTest E:\Backup\Folder1 E:\Backup\Folder2 E:\Backup\Folder3"

for %%a in (%Folders%) do (
  for %%b in (%Folders%) do (
     if not "%%a"=="%%b" (
        set "VAR%%a%%b=%%a %%b"
        )
    )
)
for /f "tokens=2,3 delims== " %%a in ('set VAR') Do (
    echo xcopy "%%a" "%%b" /E /D /C /Y /I 
)
pause
```